# IBAction Button Press (Don't want to see the press)

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction

So I have a few buttons in an application and obviously they can all be pressed and do various things...

My question is, how can you "not display" the colour change or visual aid that happens on screen once a button is pressed?

To be honest, I'm not sure how to word this or which terminology to use, but basically, when a button is pressed, I don't want any change on screen to happen (apart from whats supposed to happen in the IBAction).

It sounds counter intuitive, but I was hoping for a built in function like `IBActionPress.Visual = NO;` or something like that...

I really hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
yourUIButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Comment: This is perfect. It's exactly what I was looking for. Just had to use it in the ViewDidLoad as obviously it needs to be set before the button is actually pressed :) Thanks for posting.